# Centered content, background extends only to the left to browser edge ex: http://kibart.com/

Tags: html, css, layout

I want to mimic the white, main content area of this site -> http://kibart.com/. The content is centered but the white area extends all the way to the left of the browser. How do you achieve this effect?

Comment: Email that site and ask for their code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two elements basically creating that area which you're referring to as the one which extends all the way to the left. First is the `<div id="main-content">` and the other is `<div class="left-filler">`. `<div id="main-content">` is the `<div>` which contains all the main content and these are the styles which are assigned to it in the stylesheet:

```
#main-content {
    background-color: #fff;
    position: relative;
    width: 804px;
    padding: 30px 0 55px 0;
    float: left;
}
```

`<div class="left-filler">` is an absolutely positioned `<div>` with a white background, appearing on the left side of the main-content `<div>`, whose function is to hide the arrow-pattern image. These are the styles which are assigned to it in the stylesheet:

```
.left-filler {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 4000px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 500px;
    z-index: -20;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect. I appreciate your help.